# Char Printing in C

Tags: c

I am trying to modify some of Ritchie and Kernighan's codes but this one doesn't seem to return the expected:

character 1
character 2
character 3

... but instead some weird:

character 1
   2
character 3
   4

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{

    char cadena[10], cadinver[10], c;
    int lim,i;
    lim=10;
    i=0;

    for (i=0;(i<lim) && ((c=getchar())!=EOF);++i){
        cadena[i]=c;
        printf("%c %d",c,i);
    }
    printf("%s",cadena);
    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

I think the mistake is quite simple but I didn't make it...

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: You forgot to write a string terminator after the loop with say `cadena[i]='\0'` and also `lim=9` to leave room for it.

Comment: amongst other problems with the posted code, the variable: `cadinver[10]` is not used.

Comment: rather than the call to `system( pause );` which is not portable, use the following two lines: `while( int ch = getchar() && ch != EOF && ch != '\n' ); getchar();`

Answer (score 2):

It's a little tricky but this is what I think is happening.
When you write from your keyboard 2 and then you press enter, what you 
actually "give" to your programm is '2' '\n', which are 2 characters. So
your first getchar() gets the number 2 and the other one gets the '\n' 
character.

Try modifying your for-loop body like this:

```
 cadena[i]=c; 
 printf("%c %d",c,i);
 getchar();
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not an environment for c, but:

1. Add '\0' on the last access cadena. So after for, do cadena[i] = '\0';
2. You have an array of 10 elements. But in char *, you shall take account of '\0'. So lim shall be 9 (and not 10)
3. Use '\n' at end of your printf. Maybe helpfull.
4. I don't understand why you use system("pause")

good luck

OK - Corrected

Comment: The `pause` is to prevent a terminal window from closing before you can see the output.

Comment: `cadena[++i]` is wrong, `i` already is the correct index after the loop ends.